Projection Matrix, Introduction to Linear Algebra, Gilbert Strang, 4th ed, 4.2 Problem 30.
The problem asked me to find projection matrix $P_C$ onto the column space of A and the 3 by 3 projection matrix $P_R$ onto the row space of A. Then it asked me to multiply $B=P_CAP_R$. I got the result which is A itself, but I am not completely sure about the reason behind it.

I can clearly see why $P_CA=A$, but I am struggling to see how $AP_R=A$. I can follow the solution all the way up: Let $x=n+r$ with n in $null(A)$ and r in $C(A^T)$. Then $Ax=An+Ar=Ar$. Also $P_Rx=P_Rn+P_Rr=P_Rr$. The solution ends here, but I am struggling to see how this can be derived to show $AP_R=A$. I have tried to manipulate $AP_Rx=Ax$ but only get more confused.

Any help is appreciated!

You said you can clearly see that

$P_C A = A$

This is obvious because each column of $A$ is in the column space of $A$, and it is therefore invariant under the action of $P_C$.
We can apply a similar argument to show that $A P_R = A$. First, note that
$$A P_R = (P_R^T A^T)^T$$
The action of $P_R^T$ is to project a vector into the column space of $A^T$. By an identical argument as above, each column of $A^T$ is in the column space of $A^T$, and it is therefore invariant under $P_R^T$. Therefore, we have that $P_R^T A^T = A^T$. Then
$$A P_R = (P_R^T A^T)^T = (A^T)^T = A$$
as desired.

Wow that is so clear! Thanks for the explanation!
